# Automated Bug logging support in Test API

Tags: phpunit, simpletest

I am using SimpleTest API and PHPUnit Test API. Does any of them support automated bug logging support . And if not then how can I will provide this feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPUnit can, for example, interact with issues in

- `Trac` ( https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-ticketlistener-trac )
- `GitHub` ( https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-ticketlistener-github )
- and a couple others: http://pear.phpunit.de/

Buiding one that fits your propose sure is possible.

Also there are other ways to make PHPUnit tell you what is happening like

- [**`Test listeners`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener). Where you can really act on everything PHPUnit does.
- [**`The xml or json output`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/logging.html). That you can parse and act on it accordingly